# Are Dataverse actions analogous to SQL stored procedures?

Tags: powerapps, dataverse, power-platform

Being new to Dataverse and the Power Platform I'm trying to get up to speed. Actions are a feature I've come across today and I'm having trouble finding documentation that adequately (read: in basic enough terms!) describes what these are and whether I can think of them as being analogous to SQL stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Stored Procedure is similar to Actions/Custom APIs in Dataverse. The idea behind it - introduce some kind of packaged business logic embedded into one package.